# translate a curl PUT command into ansible uri

Tags: ansible, put, seafile-server

I want to interact with a seafile server with [its REST api](https://manual.seafile.com/develop/web_api_v2.1.html).

So far I had no problems translating POST or GET queries into the ansible uri module. However, I have a problem with getting a PUT query to work.

The following works with curl:

```
curl -X PUT -d "share_type=group&group_id=<groupid>&permission=rw" -H 'Authorization: Token <mysecrettoken>' -H 'Accept: application/json; charset=utf-8; indent=4' https://<myserverurl>/api2/repos/<mylibraryid>/dir/shared_items/?p=/
```

When I translate this to the following ansible task, it fails:

```
- name: mytask
  uri:
    url: "https://<myserverurl>/api2/repos/<mylibraryid>/dir/shared_items/?p=/"
    method: PUT
    headers: '{ "Authorization": "Token <mysecrettoken>" }'
    body: '{ "share_type": "group", "group_id": "<groupid>", "permission": "rw"}'
    body_format: json
    return_content: yes
```

I get the error:

```
HTTP Error 500: INTERNAL SERVER ERROR", "redirected": false, "server": "nginx", "set_cookie": "SERVERID=<serverid>; path=/", "status": 500, "transfer_encoding": "chunked", "url": "https://<myserverurl>/api2/repos/<mylibraryid>/dir/shared_items/?p=/", "vary": "Accept-Language, Cookie"}
```

In a python script using the requests library, I had to supply the final `?p=/` as `params={'p': '/'}`. Is this the reason for the failure? How do I correctly submit the parameter then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the `headers` as a YAML hash, not as a JSON string:

```
- name: mytask
  uri:
    url: "https://<myserverurl>/api2/repos/<mylibraryid>/dir/shared_items/?p=/"
    method: PUT
    headers: 
      Authorization: "Token <mysecrettoken>"
    body: '{ "share_type": "group", "group_id": "<groupid>", "permission": "rw"}'
    body_format: json
    return_content: yes
```

For reference, see [the docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/uri_module.html), especially the second-to-last example:

```
- uri:
    url: https://your.form.based.auth.example.com/dashboard.php
    method: GET
    return_content: yes
    headers:
      Cookie: "{{ login.set_cookie }}"
```